# SettingsApi deprecated

Tags: android, gps, location, client

Until last update I used next code:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
        builder.addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
        mLocationSettingsRequest = builder.build();

        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(
                        mGoogleApiClient,
                        mLocationSettingsRequest
                );
        result.setResultCallback(this);
```

Unfortunately after update a warning message pup-up that LocationServices.SettingsApi is deprecated. How to change my code to fit to new updates?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[**`SettingsApi`**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsApi) interface is **<s>Deprecated</s>**. You should use **GoogleApi-based API** [**`SettingsClient`**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsClient) instead.

> public class SettingsClient extends
>   GoogleApi

This API makes it easy for an app to ensure that the device's system settings are properly configured for the app's location needs.

```
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
    builder.addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest); // mLocationRequest is a Object of LocationRequest
    LocationSettingsRequest locationSettingsRequest = builder.build();

    SettingsClient settingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this);
    settingsClient.checkLocationSettings(locationSettingsRequest);
```

- [**`Get current location settings.`**](https://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings#java)
- [**`Working with the user's location settings.`**](https://google-developer-training.gitbooks.io/android-developer-advanced-course-concepts/unit-4-add-geo-features-to-your-apps/lesson-7-location/7-1-c-location-services/7-1-c-location-services.html)

Comment: can't figure out how to implement this part: PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                    settingsClient.checkLocationSettings(
                            mGoogleApiClient,
                            mLocationSettingsRequest
                    );
            result.setResultCallback(this);

Comment: sorry I am new with java.

Comment: Google just deprecated GoogleApiCLient. https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-api-client
Look at https://developer.android.com/training/location/